# React add html attribute to external component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a component that I cannot change directly, but I would like to extend.

```
import { Button } from '@external-library'

// Currently how the button component is being used
<Button click={() => doSomething()} />

// I would like to add a tabIndex to the button
<Button click={() => doSomething()} tabIndex={0} />
```

I cannot add an attribute because the component is not expecting a `tabIndex`. I cannot directly modify the Button component.

How can I extend the `<Button />` component so I can add attributes like tabIndex, etc?

I was hoping something like the following would work:

```
export default class ExtendedButton extends Button { }
// except I'm dealing with functional components
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit custom component implementation without changing its internals.

```
// You can't add tabIndex to internal button without changing its implementation
const Button = () => <button>Click</button>;
```

In such cases, you implement a wrapper with desired props:

```
const Component = () => {
  return (
    <div tabIndex={0}>
      <Button />
    </div>
  );
};
```

If the component forwarding ref (also depends to which element it forwarded in the implementation), you can use its attributes:

```
// Assumption that Button component forwards ref
const Button = React.forwardRef((props,ref) => <button ref={ref}>Click</button>);

<Button ref={myRef}/>
// Usage
myRef.current.tabIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the inner DOM button element using React refs([read here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs))

most likely the `external-lib` you use provide a `ref` prop for the `Button` component which you use to pass your own create ref

```js
 const buttonRef = useRef(null);

 <Button ref={buttonRef}/>
```

Then you can use `buttonRef.current` to add `tabIndex` when your data is ready to be populated in like

```js
useEffect( () => { 
  if(buttonRef && buttonRef.current){
    buttonRef.current.tabIndex = 2;
 }
}, [props.someProperty] );
```